# how to get only certain parameters from an array of objects in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array with this structure and I want to make a function that pushes to another array only url(key) values. 
Should I create a function like foreach? or just a filter?

```
    [{name: 'portada',url:"foto.jpg" },
    {name: 'portada2',url:"foto2.jpg" }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats a simple es6 array extenssion.
you can use map function to return new array with the wanted properties.

### ES6 syntax

```
 const imagesDataList = [{name: 'portada',url:"foto.jpg" },
     {name: 'portada2',url:"foto2.jpg" }];

 const imagesUrlsList = imagesDataList.map(imageData => imageData.url);

 console.log(imagesUrlsList);// ["foto.jpg", "foto2.jpg"]
```

### ES5 syntax with lodash

```
var imagesDataList = [{name: 'portada',url:"foto.jpg" },
    {name: 'portada2',url:"foto2.jpg" }];

var imagesUrlsList = _.map(imagesDataList, function(imageData){ 
  return imageData.url;
    });


console.log(imagesUrlsList); // ["foto.jpg", "foto2.jpg"]
```

### pure es5

```
var imagesDataList = [{name: 'portada',url:"foto.jpg" },
    {name: 'portada2',url:"foto2.jpg" }];

var imagesUrlsList = [];

for(imageData in imagesDataList){

  imagesUrlsList.push(imagesDataList[imageData].url);
}

console.log(imagesUrlsList);// ["foto.jpg", "foto2.jpg"]
```